# Falcon cors with Angular 2

Tags: python, angular, cors, falcon

I do not understand the setup below used to work but it suddenly broke.

I configured CORS on Falcon as follow (I run it via gunicorn):

```
cors = CORS(
  allow_all_origins=True,
  allow_all_headers=True,
  allow_all_methods=True
)

api = application = falcon.API(
  middleware=[
      cors.middleware,
      auth_middleware,
      sqlalchemy_middleware
  ]
)
```

On AngularJS

```
return this.authHttp.get(CONFIG.apiUrl + '/user').map(
        (res: Response) => res.json());
```

Using http.get with manually setting the token does not work.
I have access to my token in localStorage.getItem('token').

I have got the following errors:

zone.js:2019 OPTIONS http://0.0.0.0:8000/user 401 (Unauthorized)
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://0.0.0.0:8000/user. Response for preflight has invalid HTTP status code 401

I searched everywhere on the internet and I understand it is a server issue... However the server used to work with that configuration.

Let me know if you have any idea.

Cheers,

Answer (score 0):

The solution was simple, I needed to disable the authentication from the FalconAuthMiddleware on 'OPTIONS' requests in my controller.

```
auth = {
    'exempt_methods': ['OPTIONS']
}
```